# Setting up cron job to launch docker containers on ec2

Tags: docker, cron, docker-compose

I am trying to set up regular task on an amazon ec2 instance that will launch a few docker containers. 
I ve created a `startup_service.sh` script in my home directory :

```
cd ~
docker-compose pull && docker-compose up
```

In that very same home directory, I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that defines my containers and image.
I have tested this file `sh startup_service.sh` and it is working as expected

Ive added execute permission to this `startup_service.sh` file and created a cronjob with crontab -e :

```
50 11 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/ec2-user/startup_service.sh
```

However it is not working ( running `docker ps` doesnt show any containers being created or anything).

However checking the cron logs, it seems like the task is actually executed `sudo grep -C 3 "startup" /var/log/cron` :

```
Feb 27 11:42:01 ip-172-31-27-90 crond[3188]: (ec2-user) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/ec2-user)
Feb 27 11:44:00 ip-172-31-27-90 crontab[18011]: (ec2-user) LIST (ec2-user)
Feb 27 11:48:54 ip-172-31-27-90 crontab[18064]: (ec2-user) LIST (ec2-user)
Feb 27 11:50:01 ip-172-31-27-90 CROND[18153]: (ec2-user) CMD (/usr/bin/sh /home/ec2-user/startup_service.sh)
Feb 27 11:50:02 ip-172-31-27-90 CROND[18156]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb 27 11:53:05 ip-172-31-27-90 crontab[18232]: (ec2-user) LIST (ec2-user)
Feb 27 12:00:01 ip-172-31-27-90 CROND[18343]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

How can I correctly setup this cron job ?

Comment: If you are running containers as cron, most probably they would be terminated after execution. As such, they will be visible in `docker ps -a`

Comment: why would they be terminated ? This docker-compose file is launching a long task, so the containers should actually be up for a while @PalashGoel

Comment: Try to use absolute path `cd /path/to/home/directory`

Comment: Here is 2021 and I'm having the same issue with Amazon Linux 2, did you found the answer? To me it just looks like the docker-compose command does nothing in a cron. I'm trying to restart my containers daily.